# python 3.7 can't import modules

Tags: python, import, terminal, module, path

I've been trying to import some packages for scraping comments but every time it downloads properly in terminal it has a module not found error in python. I've tried making a virtual environment, using sudo, using the path in the terminal download, changing the path in terminal *and* python itself. I've tracked down the path, setup.py and pyproject.toml to use as shown above but nothing (there wasn't pyproject and many setups but they all came from Unity or inside modules). When I type 'pip3 list' all my modules appear. I pasted the code from [this website](https://thispointer.com/how-to-change-current-working-directory-in-python/) to change the directory and only edited the three paths to Users/Oscar/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages and got this: (the path of its code)

```
Current Working Directory  /Users/Oscar/Desktop/Python Scripts/Stolen Codes
Can't change the Current Working Directory
Current Working Directory  /Users/Oscar/Desktop/Python Scripts/Stolen Codes
Can't change the Current Working Directory
Current Working Directory  /Users/Oscar/Desktop/Python Scripts/Stolen Codes
```

moreover, though, when typing into the terminal 'pip3 install selenium ~/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages', I got this error:

```
ERROR: Directory '/Users/Oscar/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
```

I'm the admin so does anyone know how to fix? I've spent so long on the internet trying to import, sorry for the full-on text

Comment: What happens if you try just `pip install selenium` ?

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience(with other modules), uninstalling the module using `pip uninstall selenium` and reinstalling it using `pip install selenium` has worked. There also might be dependencies that you are missing, and that could potentially result in your error.

Answer (score 0):

first... upgrade pip:
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
after... `pip install selenium`

If your problem is not solved again

Delete all python versions. python reload.
Install python from the install file, not from the command line.
It will ask if a path should be created during the installation phase?
Check that option.